# ASP.NET MVC + Oracle: samples and how-to

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

While reading [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/), and browsing other examples on the internet regarding ASP.NET MVC with LINQ To SQL.

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have to connect to an Oracle database. The main goal of the application is to display, edit, and update data.  I am uncertain if ASP.NET MVC can work with an Oracle database.

- Has anyone ever done an ASP.NET MVC project with Oracle as the database?
- Are there any articles with sample code that you'd recommend?
- What are some easy ORMs or data access strategies that you'd recommend an ASP.NET (webforms or MVC) project use to communicate to an Oracle database?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Nhibernate](http://nhforge.org/) to get access to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC can certainly support Oracle or any other data source behind the scenes.

MVC is not tied to Linq to SQL in any way.  It's just one convenient way (among many) to get data from a datasource into your models.

As Sly pointed out, NHibernate is one ORM framework that will work for you.

Comment: If I use my own dataset, how can I connect it to mvc to display data from dataset or datatable?

Comment: Do you have any example that show how to display data from dataset or datatable in MVC?

Comment: Check out http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-26-cs.aspx.  They use Entity Framework for this example, but NHibernate will work just as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try NHibernate.